# NoClassDefFoundError thrown even after object can be created

Tags: java, apache-commons, noclassdeffounderror

I'm getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` exception on `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory` after I have already created an instance.  I can create a `LogFactory` object just fine and get an instance of `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` from it but when creating an object of type `org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc`, a `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown when this class tries to get an instance of `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` from `LogFactory`.  Seems like an exception should be thrown at line 284.(?)

Here's my code (DtUiLoggingRequest lines 282 to 294);

```
log.debug("vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv");

org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory logFactory = (org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory)LogFactory.getFactory();
Log myLog = LogFactory.getLog(DtUiLoggingRequest.class.getName());

log.debug(logFactory.getClass().getName());
log.debug(myLog.getClass().getName());

myLog.debug("This is coming from 'myLog'");

log.debug("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");

typeDesc = new org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc(DtUiLoggingRequest.class);
```

Here's what the log says;

```
DEBUG   2012-02-23 09:32:08,739 vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  
DEBUG   2012-02-23 09:32:08,739 org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl  
DEBUG   2012-02-23 09:32:08,739 org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger  
DEBUG   2012-02-23 09:32:08,739 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
ERROR   2012-02-23 09:32:08,739 Exception Details:  
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory  
    at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.class$(LogFactory.java:45)  
    at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45)  
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
    at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLogFactory(LogFactory.java:41)  
    at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:33)  
    at org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc.<clinit>(TypeDesc.java:61)  
    at com.symantec.cas.ucf.sensors.DtUiLoggingRrequest.initTypeDesc(DtUiLoggingRequest.java:294)  
    at com.symantec.cas.ucf.sensors.sap.DtUiLoggingRequest.<init>(DtUiLoggingRequest.java:58)  
    at com.symantec.cas.ucf.sensors.sap.SapSensor.OpenDevice(Sensor.java:151)  
    at com.symantec.cas.ucf.collector.SensorJob.openSensor(SensorJob.java:156)  
    at com.symantec.cas.ucf.collector.SensorJob.run(SensorJob.java:290)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: It seems you are not including `required jar files` in your classpath.

Comment: How do you run this project (servlet container, command line, ant script, etc)?

Comment: @RanRag - Yes, that's the straight forward answer. However, I am able to create an object of the same type so LogFactory is in the classpath at one point.

Comment: @Fixpoint1 - The code is running inside a Symantec SSIM event agent (collector).  The exception is not thrown if I run it outside this framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a classloader issue to me. You're working in a system with hierarchical classloaders, like a web app, and Axis is being loaded by a higher-status classloader than Commons Logging. That means that, even though Commons Logging is in your system, Axis is not allowed to see it. My wild-arsed guess would be that you're loading Axis from a JRE extension directory, but Commons Logging from your war file.

Comment: That sounds like what I was thinking.  I know that I didn't provide much detail about the environment but do you have any suggestions on how I might be able to make the LogFactory class visible?  I don't have much control over the environment other than this particular source code.  The code is running inside a Symantec SSIM event agent (hence my limited knowledge of how things work under the hood).  

I've tried loading the classes by adding the .jar libraries using ClasLoader.getSystemClassLoader() but it didn't help.  Is there some a class loader other than SystemClassLoader?

Comment: Yes, there are usually two classloaders of higher status (or lower level, depending on how you look at it). The bootstrap classloader loads the JDK's own classes, and the extension classloader loads classes from the extensions directory (i think?). I suspect that Axis is being loaded by the extensions classloader, although i'm not sure why anyone would set it up like that, nor why they would fail to supply its dependencies, like Commons Logging, too.

Comment: I would suggest finding out some definite facts about what is being loaded from where. Perhaps you could go around doing `Class.forName` for everything you can think of, and print out `getClassLoader()` for each. That might shed some light on where classes are being loaded from.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  Here's how I solved the problem.  I used getClassLoader() from the log class that I could access and I used it to load the missing classes.

Comment: Hi Tom. I have a similar problem. I am using JRE and not JDK. it happens to me only on an ubuntu server that has JRE. on my local dev it works just fine. Any solution?

Comment: Have you tried printing out the classloaders for the relevant classes, and comparing the results on your machine and the server?